# HOA - can individual homeowners sue to prevent me from building addition to the home that the HOA did not timely reject

Tags: hoa

I submitted plans to my HOA for modification of my home.  The Declaration gives them 30 days to reject, or they are deemed approved.  They missed the 30 days, but then later rejected the plans.  Because they were deemed approved, we applied for a building permit.  Now, individual homeowners (not the HOA) are suing us to stop our modification.  First, do the individual homeowners have standing?  Second, is the HOA an indispensable party?

Comment: The law differs materially from state to state and the relevant governing documents are also important and differ from one HOA to another.

Answer (score 5):

There are just too many variables to know. There's both the wording on the HOA Covenants, and state and local laws. Many localities, as just one example of a requirement for building modifications, require posting at a property the proposed design for some amount of time. You should talk with a lawyer, or at the very least if you have a contractor handling the the modification, have them warrant that they have reviewed the HOA Covenants and applicable laws and the modification has complied with all requirements (get an indemnification in writing). A contractor in your area is going to be more familiar with the requirements than people on the internet.